# Auto send email when new post has created in django

Tags: python, django

When I save my post, I want to send email for user automatically. But it's not working. This is my code

signals.py

```sh
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from mysite.models import Post, Email
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from blog.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER

@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def SendEmail(sender , instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        emails = list(Email.objects.values('email'))
        recepients = []
        for i in range(0, len(emails)):
            recepients.append(emails[i]['email'])
            pass
        send_mail('New post on blog', str(instance.title), EMAIL_HOST_USER, recepients, fail_silently=False)
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the signal **itself**'s not working, is because of this:
By default `signals.py` doesn't get automatically loaded into your app, so you have to manually import it.
Assuming your app is named `post`, you need to modify your app's config file (`post/apps.py`) accordingly.

This is an example how:

```py
# post/apps.py #
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PostConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'post'    
    def ready(self):
        print(">DEBUG::loading_signals")
        import post.signals
        # other stuff you need imported on app's startup
```

If you're still not receiving signals, try specifying your app's default config class inside your app's `__init__.py` file, like so:

```py
# post/__init__.py #
default_app_config = "post.apps.PostConfig"
```

from Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) itself:

> Where should this code [signals] live?
>
> Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live
>   anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to **avoid** the
>   application’s root module and its models module to minimize
>   side-effects of importing code.
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
>   submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are
>   connected in the `ready()` method of your application configuration
>   class. If you’re using the `receiver()` decorator, import the signals
>   submodule inside `ready()`.

References:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

Comment: I forgot import signals in apps.py. But i still don't know why we do it.

Comment: @Blind think of  `signals.py` as just another file in your project. It can be named anything (e.g. `post_signals.py`) and it can reside anywhere (e.g. `mysite/signal_folder`).